# Ugrading to xcode 8, UINavigationController push animation issue

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios10, xcode8, uiviewanimationtransition

I have upgraded to xcode 8, After upgrading, my app is behaving totally abnormal.

When i am pushing viewcontroller2 from viewcontroller1, The animation is totally abnormal.

The textfields,buttons, other ui controls in viewcontroller2 also animates(appears with large size and then moves to actual size). Why i am getting such an strange animation? I am really surprized by such a worst update from Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging and tearing my hair, I just come up with an answer.

Actually the problem was:

Keyboard were open in viewController1, and then i pushed viewController2.  iOS 10 added some funky animation by its own.

After too many tries, i observed that when keyboard is closed in viewController1, and then pushing new viewController, that funky animation gone away.

So Solution is -> just add line `[self.view endEditing:YES];` to close the keyboard, before pushing the new ViewController.

Dont know how much worst OS+Xcode they are developing, with such a bugs.